# svg path not visible

Tags: javascript, svg, path

Why is this path not visible? I am creating the path dynamically with javascript, but the path is not visible on screen, it is present in the DOM though.

```
var svg = document.getElementById('svg');
var path = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/svg', 'path');
path.setAttribute('d', 'M100,100 L100,100');
path.setAttribute('style', 'stroke:black;fill:none;');
path.setAttribute('matrix', '1,0,0,1,100,100');
svg.appendChild(path);
```

Or as a [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f1g27ps1/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've two separate problems

1. The SVG namespace is actually http://www.w3.org/2000/svg
2. You're not drawing a line that goes anywhere, it starts at 100,100 and finishes at the same place.

Comment: As Robert said, your line starts and finishes at the same point. "M100,100 L100,100" means move to 100,100 and draw a line to 100,100. Perhaps you mean "M100,100 l100,100" - notice the "L" is lowercase, which means you are giving coordinates *relative* to the current position.

Answer (score 2):

You are creating a path, that has a starting-point at `100,100` (denoted by `M100,100`), and drawes a "line" to that exact same point (`L100,100`), so you are not drawing a line at all.

SVG-paths differentiate between absolute and relative coordinates. Using capital letters, you are indicating absolute values. Small letter are used for relative coordinate-values (relative to the coordinate where you have drawn or moved before).

You should either use small letters, to indicate a relative path: `M100,100 l100,100` means, start at `100,100` and draw a line to a point, that lies 100px in x and 100px in y-direction.

Or you should use another coordinate entireley, like e.g.: `M100,100 L110,110` (start at `100,100` and draw a line to `110,110`).

Answer (score 0):

```
var path_elemnt = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "path")  ;
var sgv_element = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg")  ;
```

Comment: yes i know but as they say me show code :p

Comment: Better to have explanation + code.